# PowerShell how to add a custom common parameter?

Tags: powershell

I would like to make a custom -Force switch a common parameter.

I have three functions that each take the parameter.

function A calls function B, function B calls function C

I would like to call function A with the custom -Force parameter and have it propagate as a common parameter, without having to do something like this:

```
function B() {

    [cmdletbinding()]

    param([switch] $Force)   

    # NOTE: THIS CHECK IS THE PART I WANT TO ELIMINATE
    # I WANT -Force TO BE PASSED ALONG AS A COMMON PARAMETER
    if ($Force) {
        C -Force
    }
    else {
        C
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can *make* it a common parameter, but you can do this:

```powershell
Function B() {

    [cmdletbinding()]

    param([switch] $Force)   

    C -Force:$Force

    }

}
```

Comment: oooh that looks nice!  This means I can make -Force false right?  I couldn't figure out how to exclude or include the switch without a hardcoded if/else

Comment: Yes, this works for any switch parameter, you can use `:` and specify `$true` or `$false` explicitly (or use a variable).

Answer (score 1):

The common parameters are built into PowerShell itself.  You may be interested to know that -Force is not a common param, rather it is a switch built into each Cmdlet.  So, if you want to implement -Force into all of your Function/cmdlets, you're going the right route by defining a switch parameter for each cmdlet.

For your reference, here is a list of the common parameters.

```
-Debug (db)
-ErrorAction (ea)
-ErrorVariable (ev)
-OutVariable (ov)
-OutBuffer (ob)
-PipelineVariable (pv)
-Verbose (vb)
-WarningAction (wa)
-WarningVariable (wv

 risk mitigation parameters
-WhatIf (wi)
-Confirm (cf)
```